# How to mute the microphone on Key-Down and unmute it on Key-Up?

Tags: software-recommendation, keyboard, microphone

What I would like to have is:

1. By default the microphone should be **muted**
2. When <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is Down the microphone should **unmute**
3. When <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is Up the microphone should **mute**

(Basically convert my Skype to act like a Walkie-talkie with a [push-to-talk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_to_talk) functionality)

I [found](https://superuser.com/questions/172970/hotkey-to-mute-mic-on-mac-os-x/174009#174009) the AppleScript that can change the volume input of the microphone, so the first step was easy, but I didn't find any way to even assign the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to a script. Note that my <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key is turned off and I would't like to sTART experiencing something like tHIS.

If the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is very special I wouldn't mind using another key, but I want to achieve the same functionality.

**Edit**:
Probably it is not really possible to do it without using any application, so if there is an app that can do that, it would also work for me.

Comment: Maybe this functionality could be added to the app/software you will use for recording. So, in which application you'll use it?

Comment: @nuc Basically I want it to use it when I'm talking on Skype.. I want to use it as a walkie-talkie.. in order to talk you should press a button..! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the AppleScript that inspects the key state and handles the mic enabling and muting:

```
if (modKeyDowntest()) then
  tell application "System Events" to set volume input volume 100
  repeat while modKeyDowntest()
  end repeat
  tell application "System Events" to set volume input volume 0
end if

on modKeyDowntest()
  set modKeyDown to do shell script "~/opt/checkModifierKeys shift"
  set modKeyDown to modKeyDown as integer
  set modKeyDown to modKeyDown as boolean
end modKeyDowntest
```

Note, that

- the script depends on the [`checkModifierKeys` command line app](http://www.klieme.ch/pub/checkModifierKeys.zip) (and it's path).
- inspects the state of <kbd>shift</kbd> instead of <kbd>caps lock</kbd> (other possibilities are <kbd>cmd</kbd>, <kbd>option</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd> and <kbd>caps lock</kbd> - <kbd>caps lock</kbd>, however, means the *status* of caps lock, not the key state!)

In the second step we bind the script to a key shortcut. There are many applications that can do this (some listed in [an answer in SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/bind-a-key-to-a-commandline-command-in-mac-os-x/264943#264943)) or as an Automator service. (C&P from Lri's answer...)

> One more option is to save the script as an Automator service:
>
> - Open Automator and choose the *Service* template.
> - *Utilities — Run Shell Script / Run AppleScript*.
> - *Service receives [no input] in [any application]*.
> - Add the script to the text area and save.
> - Assign a shortcut in *System Preferences — Keyboard — Keyboard Shortcuts — Services*.

So, I assigned <kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to the script above and it enables the mic, keeping it unmuted as long as I hold <kbd>shift</kbd>. The mic is muted again when I release <kbd>shift</kbd>.

Comment: There might be some CLI app to inspect the key state of caps lock, so checkModifierKeys could very well be replaced to make the script act on caps lock.

Comment: And for this question the mute status is the opposite as needed, so invert the volumes to get the right functionality.

Comment: Thanks for that.. I don't have time now to test all these things.. but basically what I want is to use Skype as a Walkie-talkie... hold a key to talk..! So I would prefer one key like F5 or something if the CapsLock is out of the question :)

Comment: Can you please update the answer to match the question as needed.. and I think that's the answer..

Comment: On Mojave, _Services_ are named _Quick Actions_. And there is no need for `tell application "System Events" to`, this will force an alert requesting more rights for the current application... (see an example of muting the mic [here](https://robservatory.com/silently-mute-the-mic-input-via-applescript/))

Answer (score 1):

I have not used it, but [Skii](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/36677/skii) plugin for Skype, seems to provide what you're looking for:

> Skii is a very easy to use and simple plug-in that uses the Skype API to simplify the Push-to-Talk function. The app gives the user the possibility to control the Skype Push-To-Talk function with just one button! a small utility that will definetly improve your Skype user experience but also your overall workflow.

Comment: even though the other is more wide and thats is what I asked.. i think I have to go with the other one :) thanks for the Skii..

Comment: @lipis I would pick the other one as well :)