# How to toggle microphone off/on?

Tags: macos, microphone

On macos (Monterey/version 12) how can I toggle the microphone off/on (mute/unmute)? If there's no control for this, is there a way to script it for macos specifically to achieve the desired effect of quickly toggling the microphone?

Various apps use the microphone (eg web/webrtc calling, desktop calling/meeting apps, etc) and don't actually mute when I select that option, they simply turn off the audio stream. How can I control my own microphone from the OS instead of the various oddities and quirks of app developers (regardless of whether it's in browser or otherwise)?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mute the microphone on Key-Down and unmute it on Key-Up?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11394/how-to-mute-the-microphone-on-key-down-and-unmute-it-on-key-up)

Comment: Thanks Saaru, it only does in part. I found 2 other solutions along the lines of what I was looking for and can answer the question more directly as well as link to what you've shared here.

Comment: Related read [How The Bleep: Mute Your Mic From Anywhere on macOS](https://medium.com/macoclock/how-in-the-bleep-do-i-mute-my-mic-anywhere-on-macos-d2fa1185b13) – create an Action workflow via Automator and add a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Sound** preferences control panel provides the control for muting and adjusting the microphone in the [**Input**] tab. When adjusting the volume slider to the far left/down it results in the calling apps warning me my microphone is muted, as expected.

For convenience I searched in the App Store for "mute mic" and found [MuteKey](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mutekey/id1509590766) which when open allows toggling the microphone off and on (and has settings for opening on login).

Related to this a scripted solution is mentioned in [Saaru's comment above](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11394/how-to-mute-the-microphone-on-key-down-and-unmute-it-on-key-up) which is super helpful and I might try as well. However that scripted solution is aiming to solve a slightly different, related problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just tried [MuteKey](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mutekey/id1509590766?mt=12) on macOS Big Sur and it did the job very well. On my default installation, the hotkeys were <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>; I had to select `Device` > `All Input Devices` to get it working globally.

[image]

*Note: I'm not 100% sure if this what the original person was asking, but I had the same question on the title and this was the first result on Google, so I figured I could make it easier for the next person!*

Comment: How is this different from the [existing answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/442795/489896)?

Comment: You're right, I hadn't noticed that the existing answer also mentions this app as one of its suggestions. Although my answer includes the fact that I tested it successfully and adds more specific instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I was turning down the built-in mic slider in the Input tab of the System Sound Settings but for some reason it always came back up a notch. I found that you can open Audio MIDI Setup (can search with cmd+space), click the mic you want to mute, then check Mute.

This is nice if you don't want to install anything extra.

Answer (score 0):

I have ligitic KeyBoard and there is a button to do this function, actually it activates the Mute checkbox of the system Mic in the **Audio MIDI Setup** thanks to @VerboseOaf for his tip.

Comment: That's great you found a solution to your particular scenario, but how does this answer the question being asked short of buying a (assuming) Logitech keyboard?  This appears to be more commentary than a bona fide answer.